# SPSS Python without the awful Code Editor

Tags: python, scripting, editor, spss

I am stuck with SPSS Version 19 and the editor is driving me nuts: slow and ugly as hell (as befits SPSS, which UI is stuck at the early 70s).
So I am using Notepad++ to write my scripts, but is there some way to EXECUTE them from Notepad++?
Both *.sps files and python scripts would be great, but only Python scripts would suffice.

Comment: May be you can ask to the [author of the python plugin](http://mpcabd.igeex.biz/notepad-plugin-to-run-python-scripts/) ?

Comment: That sounds like a great Idea! Thanks!
i have just realized that you can "query" spss for the current file, si a Python script does not to run inside spss - it can be "stand alone". Could you kindly post your comment as answer?

Comment: why not :) it is done .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested ;)

May be you can ask to the [author's notepad++ python plugin](http://mpcabd.igeex.biz/notepad-plugin-to-run-python-scripts/) ?

Hope this could help